# Different forms for a same list in different webparts

Tags: 2010, web-part, list-form

I have a page where I display 4 times a same list, but with a different view, and different audience. I can easily have different views for my webparts, but I don't know how to have one different form (new element form) for each webpart. Because when I modify the form (with  "list settings" => "column classement"), it modifies the form for all the webparts. But I would like to hide some fields for one webpart, change order for another...

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this with Sharepoint Designer.

- Select in Sharepoint Designer your list
- Create a new Form for each of your web parts (ex. newitemtest.aspx in the picture)
  [image: list forms]
- Edit the new form removing the fields you want to hide from the userd
- Provide the users with the new links 
  ex. if the  list is called test:

  > Lists/test/newitemtest.aspx

Here is a link [Create a custom list form using SharePoint Designer](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-a-custom-list-form-using-SharePoint-Designer-917d8fdb-ee00-4441-adb3-a94612d1d105)